# How to create a shortcut for "/" in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Creating a shortcut for 'Files' opens Nautilus to /home directory. However, I wish to open it to /. How do I do this?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://askubuntu.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new desktop entry:

```
$ cd Desktop/
$ touch nautilus-root.desktop
```

Write in newly created file :
(Provide a source for icon or leave it as is)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=nautilus-root
Exec=gksudo nautilus /
Type=Application
Icon=<icon source>
```

Finally give it execute permission:

```
$ chmod +x nautilus-root.desktop
```